# images jump down - on web server only

Tags: html, css, image

When I have a look at the local copy of my website the images are in the right places; but when I upload the site to a web server, five of the images jump down on Google Chrome and Firefox, and all six of them on Internet Explorer.

The website URL is http://website5.jscomputingservices.co.uk/new/  and the image code is :

```
<img style="margin-left:35%; float:left; margin-top:-63%; border-radius:5px;" src="img/Home/1.JPG" width="200px">   

<img style="margin-left:53%; float:left; margin-top:-60%; border-radius:5px;" src="img/Home/2.JPG" height="200px" class="rotate90"> 

<img style=" float:right; margin-top:-60%; border-radius:5px;" src="img/Home/3.JPG" height="200px" class="rotate90">

<img style="width:200px; margin-left:35%;  margin-top:-35%; border-radius:5px; float:left;" src="img/interiors/HomePageLightBlue.jpg"></font>

<img style="width:200px; margin-left:56%;  margin-top:-35%; border-radius:5px; float:left;" src="img/portfolio/oldbarn.jpg"></font>

<img style="width:200px; margin-left:77%;; margin-top:-35%; border-radius:5px; float:left; "   src="img/services2.png"></font>
```

Comment: Your styling on those images is a bit disastrous. Best to remove all of those margins, floats etc and start again. Wrap the images in a container, and then set them to `display: inline-block`, or float them all left etc.

Comment: Agreed with @ralph.m. Don't make this crazy weird things. The layout helps you to arrange all items without define custom margins for each element.